# Php mysql to do task after 30 seconds

Tags: php, mysql

How can I get a mysql query command to execute after 30 seconds of visiting a php site?

Comment: There are various ways to do this, but for anybody to make a really good recommendation, more information is needed. What do you what to do? What kind of environment is your site running in, shared hosting or a web server?

Answer (score 0):

You can make AJAX request for a php script which executes your mysql query, use timer in js.

Comment: @Drake Please specify your needs of what kind of situation you're having then we can help you more specifically.

Answer (score -2):

you could put your mysql query into another page and then with your current one, set the header: refresh to that page. Would that be suitable for what you are looking for?

```
<?php
header("refresh:30;url=\"http://www.yourdomain.com/mysqlquery.php");
?>
```

Put this at the very top of your page before any html is sent to the browser.

Comment: Even though it's not clear what OP wants, this answer is probably not the path to take. I would avoid something like this at all costs for many reasons. Would *you* use this? If not, don't teach it. If so, I'd be happy to explain why this is bad.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head when you said that the OP is unclear in what he wants and my suggestion does exactly what the OP asked for. Yes there may be vulnerabilities in it however as you have already pointed out, the OP hasn't said either way whether this is going to be put into a production environment. They may just be playing around with the code, to see what is possible. Please do not down vote an answer without giving reasons.

Comment: For one thing, this redirects the page after 30 seconds, every time, to a file that executes an sql query. Then what? Besides, it won't work if the user doesn't hang around for 30 seconds, plus there are about a million ways to avoid something this messy.

Comment: bu a redirect means leaving the page, the mysql query may have an if statement around it (at least it should do) so it won't execute a second time with the same parameters. Maybe the whole point of it is that the user has to wait around for 30 seconds otherwise they aren't allowed access or something. I am sorry but my answer is perfectly valid in this instance.

Comment: Why would you want to redirect the user? What if they are filling out a form for instance? This answer needs to spell out the whole thing, with disclaimers, if this is what you really want to do.  It's not your fault the question is way too broad, but I just don't think this is a good solution, necessary, or a good idea to teach newbs.

Comment: @Mike: Having to wrap the query in an `if` statement doesn't fix the design problem you've created here, it just compounds upon it.  Forcing the user to redirect after 30 seconds makes for a very poor user experience (imagine the phrase "hey, I was reading that!").  It also doesn't guarantee that the script will run, since the user might navigate away within 30 seconds.  Scheduled tasks are a server-side concern.  Relying on the client to perform them is just asking for them not to be performed.

Comment: Sure I understand the points you both are making, but consider rapidshare or megaupload, the user has to wait a set time for a link to be displayed, maybe the OP is looking for something like that. I am merely saying, that my response does exactly what the OP is looking for. No warranty is provided and yes I could have been clearer with the pitfalls of it but as with every system, you can't cover everything.

Comment: @Mike: Both rapidshare and megaupload have server-side constraints to prevent a user from skipping the wait period.  Any client-side code is just for UX purposes.  Your answer has no server-side component, you're entirely depending on the client to fulfill the requirement.  There's a difference between "not covering everything" and "sending the OP in the wrong direction."