# Get a mysql_query script to execute 30 seconds after visiting the php site

Tags: php, android, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Php mysql to do task after 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220331/php-mysql-to-do-task-after-30-seconds)

is there a way to get a mysql_query script to execute 30 seconds after visiting the php site.

This would be on a mobile device specifically the android device. After my user clicks submit i would like the mysql_query script to run after 30 seconds has passed.

Comment: Please modify your original post, not duplicate!

Answer (score 1):

Directly no, because PHP is Request based, which means after the request nothing is running anymore.

You could however create some kind of queue (e.g. in the database) and let a background worker work the queue. That can eighter be a PHP script called by a cron job every minute (but then it may get executed 60s later, but easy to implement) or a deamon on the server running in the background (hard(er) to implement and you need access to the server).

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript, for example with jQuery this might look something like:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop form from submitting when submit is clicked
        setTimeout(function() { // set a 30 second timer to make an ajax request to your php script
        $.ajax('mysqlscript.php');
    }, 30000);
});
```

Comment: As long as the user is still on your page/app 30 seconds later.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that.
There are not a single reason to execute SQL queries with delay.
Just run it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Javascript for this.

eg: using the setTimeout() function.

```
$query4=mysql_query("select id, price from pricelist where id='$result3[id]'");
$result4=mysql_query($query4);

// **Example:**
function queryTimeout(){
  var t=setTimeout("doQuery()",30000);<br />
}

function doQuery(){
  $query4=mysql_query("select * from table");
  $result4=mysql_query($query4);
}
```

However I am no javascript expert, this is just off the top of my head.

Comment: Or like user916336 said, you could also use AJAX. :)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript options proposed here are not safe because if user closes the browser, the callback will never be performed.

Using a cron job isn't an option if you really need to execute the script 30 seconds later, but it's ok if you need to execute "some time later". To make a daemon is the best option, but it's difficult to implement and it isn't the most "compatible" option.

Try this (I haven't tested!!): Instead to make a simple AJAX call or a complete page access, make another AJAX call when page is completed:

```
// This is the page you load and 30 seconds after it is loaded you want to call mysql
....
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
     url: "callMYSQL.php",
     async: true
   });
});
```

When document is loaded (case you load a new page, it you call it through AJAX you just have to call AJAX twice), it will call to *callMYSQL.php*. This PHP file must wait 30 seconds (*sleep(30)*) and later do whatever you need.

Note: This solution needs you increase the time a PHP script can be alive.
Note2: I can't understand why you need it, perhaps you should redesing your app.

Answer (score 0):

How about rethinking the problem- you want to be able to find all users who clicked the button over 30 seconds ago right?

You don't need to wait 30 seconds to perform the query: when they click the button, you execute the SQL query immediately, and update a field on the user's table called something like time_clicked.

Then you can just find the users you want by performing a query:

```
<?php
    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where time_clicked < '" .
        date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime('-30 seconds')) . "'");
?>
```